# How do I format this EJS ternary conditional properly?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a form and depending on a variable stored in `res.locals.isModel`, I want the `action` attribute of the form to be dynamic.

My attempt looks something like this:

```
<form action=<%= (isModel) ? "/models/<%= model._id %>/comments" : "/photographers/<%= photographer._id %>/comments" %> method="POST">

//all form fields here

</form>
```

However, when the code compiles, it says: `Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".`

I am sure I am formatting something incorrectly, but cannot figure out what. Or is this line of code just impossible with EJS? I am sure this is obvious to you guys, but just in case, depending on the route, I am passing in a `model` or `photographer` object into this EJS template (ie. `model._id` or `photographer._id`).

EDIT:

Actually, I am at work so I cannot test this...but would this work?

```
<form action=<%= (isModel) ? "/models/" + model._id + "/comments" : "/photographers/" + photographer._id + "/comments" %> method="POST">

    //all form fields here

    </form>
```

Comment: I suspect you can't nest `<%= ... %>` like that, but the second version looks like it would probably work.

Comment: You could also try ES6 template literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my solution worked correctly. Thank you.

```
<form action=<%= (isModel) ? "/models/" + model._id + "/comments" : "/photographers/" + photographer._id + "/comments" %> method="POST">

    //all form fields here

    </form>
```